# c ++ , getting a 'no operator ">>" matches these operands'. For a function that reads a file

Tags: c++

I have the error in this code: in the while loop for '>>' in " in>>point"

```
void FileRead(const int cap,const string point,int counter)
{

    ifstream in;
    in.open("sample_strings.txt"); //ifstream in;  in.open("sample_data.txt");

    if (in.fail())
        cout<<"sample_data not opened correctly"<<endl;

    while(!in.eof() && counter<cap)
    {
        in>>point[counter];
        counter++;
    }

    in.close();
}
```

I tried implementing the operator >> I need but i still get the error.

```
ifstream & operator>>(ifstream & in, ARRAY & Original)
{
    cout<<"operator>> has been called\n";

    Original.counter = 0;

    while(!in.eof() && Original.count<Original.cap)
    {
        in>>Original. point[Original.counter];
        (Original.counter)++;
    }

    return in;
}
```

I'm implementing the read file function to read into a constructor's array when i pass it

the private functions I have are these

```
private:

string *point;

int counter;

int cap;
```

I'm still new to c++, so any small help to understanding this would help.

Comment: Do **not** use `in.eof()` to control the loop for reading values! (this is a general advice and has nothing directly to do with your problem) Your loop should look something like this: `for (; counter < cap && in >> point[counter]; ++counter) { ... }`.

Comment: That isn't your only error; believe me. You're reading into a string index slot that likely doesn't exist. Side Note: I wanna find every instructor/book that teaches `while (!in.eof())` and slow roast them on an open fire.

Comment: You didn't post the whole error. Odds are it mentions exactly what operands you're trying to use, which would tell us exactly why it's failing.

Comment: Your question contains code and errors you're encountering, but doesn't state what is likely obvious to only-you: *What are you trying to do?* We know there are errors, but tell us what this is *supposed* to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read into a `const string`. Instead of passing `const string point`, pass `string& point` to pass as a modifiable reference to the string.

The line `in>>point[counter]` is calling `operator[]` on `point`, and then calling `operator>>`. But because `point` is a `const string`, `operator[]` returns a `const char&`, which shouldn't be read into. You want it to return `char&`, so `point` has to be non-const.